# Conjonctions de temps

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

Est-ce que les conjonctions de temps que j'ai choisies conviennent ici ?

> 1) **Tant que** vous n'aurez pas renoncé à la cigarette, vous continuerez à
>   tousser.
>
> 2) **Depuis qu**'il avait renoncé à la cigarette, il se sentait beaucoup
>   mieux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les deux choix sont corrects. Il y a quelques autres possibilités ;

1- Aussi longtemps que vous n'aurez pas renoncé à la cigarette, vous continuerez à tousser.

2- Du jour où il avait renoncé à la cigarette, il se sentait beaucoup mieux.